# cheap air travel tickets through blind company

Tags: air-travel, budget, opaque-provider

A couple of years ago there used to be a website where given the origin/destination and travel dates they would answer, after some time, with a price offer, in theory, beating market prices.
The trick here was that you wouldn't know the company before accepting.

I don't remember the name of the website. 
Is there still such a service?

Comment: I think it was [Priceline](https://www.priceline.com/) that first made this famous.  Nowadays it's known generically as [opaque booking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_travel_inventory) and there are several sites that offer it.

Comment: Kayak also has secret airlines in their results sometimes

Answer (score 3):

- If I remember right that might've been **Vayama**, they changed the program to directly offering [Secret Fare](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7943/why-is-there-a-secret-carrier-option-for-a-flight). The closest they now seem to have to this is a dubious seeming "Exclusive Phone Offer:"

[image: Screenshot of Vayama]

- **Priceline** offers [Express Deals](https://www.priceline.com/flights?modal=express-deals).

[image: Screenshot of Priceline Express Deals offer]

- **Hopper** briefly offered a "Secret Fare" program as well but [shut it down](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/hopper-ceases-secret-fares-program-300661838.html).